# how to recognise the generic declaring type?

Tags: c#, reflection

Say that you've got IList or List as a property.  How do you work out that it is a List, or an IList?  Can this be done without relying on trial and error?

The name of the type tends to be something like List`1.  Is it reasonable to consider a string hack?

```
class Program {

    public class Class1 {
        public int a { get; set; }

        public IList<int> list { get; set; }


        public List<int> concreteList { get; set; }
    }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Test1();
        Test2();
    }

    private static void Test1()
    {
        var t = typeof (Class1);
        var p = t.GetProperty("list");

        if (p.PropertyType.IsInterface && p.PropertyType.IsGenericType)
        {
            var ps = p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();
            var underlying = p.PropertyType.GetInterface("IList");

            var b = underlying == typeof (IList<>);

        }
    }

    private static void Test2() {
        var t = typeof(Class1);
        var p = t.GetProperty("concreteList");

        if (!p.PropertyType.IsInterface && p.PropertyType.IsGenericType) {
            var ps = p.PropertyType.GetGenericArguments();

            var underlying3 = p.PropertyType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

            var b = underlying3 == typeof (List<>);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you can get the property value then testing for its type can be quite straight-forward (see Guffa's answer). However, if you want to find it out without invoking the property then your code is almost there - for example,

```
var t = p.PropertyType;
if (t.IsGenericType && !t.IsGenericTypeDefinition && !t.IsInterface && !t.IsValueType) 
{
   // we are dealing with closed generic classes 
   var typeToTest = typeof (List<>);
   var tToCheck = t.GetGenericTypeDefinition();
   while (tToCheck != typeof(object)) 
   {
      if (tToCheck == typeToTest) 
      {
         // the given type is indeed derived from List<T>
         break; 
      }
      tToCheck = toCheck.BaseType;
   }
}
```

`IsGenericType` indicates that the type is generic - can be open (`List<T>`) or closed (`List<int>`). `IsGenericTypeDefinition` indicates if the generic type is an open type or not. `GetGenericTypeDefinition` on closed/open generic type will return the generic definition (i.e. the open generic type).

Comment: that works.  Before I accept the answer, is the only way to generically determine the base type to do this "List`1".Split('`')[0]?  i.e. GetGenericTypeDefinition().Name.Split('`')[0]

Comment: @sgtz, if you wish to find out the friendly name of generic type i.e. `List` instead of List`1 then AFAIK, string manipulation is the way to go!

Answer (score 2):

Just use the `is` keyword:

```
IList<int> list = ...get a collection from somewhere

if (list is List<int>) {
  // the IList<int> is actually a List<int>
} else {
  // the IList<int> is some other kind of collection
}
```

Comment: main reason for not using that approach is because it involves a trial and error approach for every permutation of List<T>

Comment: @sgtz: Well, if you don't even know what the collection contains, then you can just use reflection, as you can't use anything else to access the contents of the list anyway.